# Bloom Filter which does not fit in RAM

Tags: distributed-systems, hash, bloom-filters

Is it possible to efficiently create a bloom filter with 10^12 buckets on a single machine with 32GB of RAM and a hard drive. We can assume that the keys are already on the disk and are small in size?

Comment: This feels more like it's a question about implementation than about computational fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

A [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) doesn't have "buckets".

You can make a Bloom filter of any size you want.  The smaller it is, the higher the false positive rate.

This should be covered in any good introduction to Bloom filters, of which there are many.